# Add dynamic keys to object in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 3623,
    "identifier" : "sec_123",
    "elements" : {
        "title" : "elem_abc",
        "sub_title" : "elem_def",
        "media" : "elem_ghi",
        "button" : "elem_jkl"
    }
}
```

I want this to be modified like this:

```
"sec_123" : {
    "title" : "elem_abc",
    "sub_title" : "elem_def",
    "media" : "elem_ghi",
    "button" : "elem_jkl",
    "give_us_call" : "elem_mno"
},
```

Is there a way to do this using MongoDb aggregation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: "$identifier",
              v: "$elements"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_4LmySnmzIZ)